# AttributeError at /media/.. when requesting file in media folder Django development stage

Tags: python, django, media

When I am reqeuesting media files (.png in this case) in the media folder in development I get this error:

**AttributeError at /media/test.png
This FileResponse instance has no `content` attribute. Use `streaming_content` instead.**

Request: http://localhost:8000/media/test.png

I added below to the url patterns:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And below to the settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Static files are working just fine.

What do I overlook?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hello if you have debug  set to True you have to  use  this:

first go to you settings and set all you static file directories in

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
list of your static file,.......,]
```

the second step you should have this in your urls.py

```
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0])
```

note:there is a difference between static_root and staticfile_dirs

static_root is only used for production

this is my mail for more explanation :nguewofoss@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Christan,
Thanks for your reply.
The static files are working properly, requesting media files gives above error. Do you have an idea why that could be?

Comment: are you in production? if yes  do  you  use heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In the newer django version staticfiles are rendered with a streamingHttpResponse, this doesn't have a content attribute.

I found below code in my code that points to the (non existing) content attribute:

```
if b'<html' in response.content[:100].lower():
```

I added this to resolve the problem:

```
if not hasattr(response, 'content'):
    return response
if b'<html' in response.content[:100].lower():
```

Thanks all!